# how can I define a customized loss function using logits but not probability when using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to apply augmented conventional cross-entropy loss with an additional loss term as follows:

```
y_pred = softmax(Wh_t / tau)
augmented_loss = D_KL(y_true || y_pred)
total_loss = crossentropy_loss + alpha*augmented_loss
```

Where alpha and tau are hyperparameters. Here, the augmented loss is similar to the crossentroypy loss but the difference is that before the logits(Wh_t) passing to the softmax function, the logits is divided by hyperparameter tau.

So I want to define a customised loss using logits instead of probability. I have read the tensorflow tutorial like this:

```
def custom_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))

class CustomMSE(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, regularization_factor=0.1, name="custom_mse"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.regularization_factor = regularization_factor

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        mse = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))
        reg = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(0.5 - y_pred))
        return mse + reg * self.regularization_factor
```

But the `y_pred` is the probability but not logits. I have spent one day to read the source code and look through every related blogs but not find the anwser.

Here is my model which customize the conventional crossentropy loss:

```
class Customloss(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, name="custom_crossentropy"):
        super().__init__(name=name)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):

        return -tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.log(y_pred)*y_true, 0))

model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Embedding(input_dim=cfg.vocab_size, output_dim=cfg.embedding_size,
                            input_length=cfg.seq_length),
        layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(200,  return_sequences=True)),
        layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(200)),
        layers.Dense(cfg.hidden_unit, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dropout(cfg.keep_prob),
        layers.Dense(cfg.num_classes, activation='softmax')
        ])
    
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
             loss=Customloss,
             metrics=['accuracy',
                     keras.metrics.Recall()])
```

Can anyone help me define a custom loss function using logits in tensorflow?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try your function. It should work. Input to loss function doesn't matter - if you are using logits instead of probabilities - the model will just learn other weights. But it will train anyway